# Why does almond milk make eggs stick to a nonstick pan?

Tags: eggs, milk

I was doing an experiment when I was making eggs this morning, and tried friendly farms almond milk instead of regular milk in my eggs, and the eggs stuck to the pan, when they normally won't without anything. Why did this happen?

Method:
crack eggs
pour in a little almond milk
cook
scrape out whatever skin formed to the pan

Comment: I would just like to say that I solely use almond milk when I cook eggs and I have never had this issue. I have both scrambled and made omelets this way and never have had them stick. I do use butter in the pan as an oil for extra "non-stick" and flavor, if you are not using a little bit of butter or oil in the pan I would suggest doing that (but not too much!!).

Comment: As noted in the existing answer, it's a bit difficult to answer your question if we don't know your entire method. Do you use any sort of fat to grease the pan? Also, is this unsweetened/unflavored (hopefully... I can't imagine vanilla eggs unless you're making French toast!)?

Comment: no, I didn't use any fat of any type in the pan, and what I normally do is milk, eggs, mix while cooking, then add salsa after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  the friendly farms almond milk you used is the original variety, this has sugar in it in the way of cane juice so that's why your eggs did what they did.